# How Spanning Tree Protocol Provides Redundancy in path in L2 Layer?

Tags: networking, spanning-tree

I have very basic question related to Spanning Tree Protocol how it provides Redundancy in path this is something I read somewhere about STP but what I believe is it disable Network Redundancy .

Whats is your view Guys?

"Note sure this question belongs to SO " ignores it if it doesn't.

Comment: Off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Spanning Tree Protocol takes a graphs with cycles and reduces it to a minimal spanning tree, which you are correct that takes out redundant lines. However, if these lines were enabled the network would break and not run. Without STP a layer 2 802.1 network will forward the traffic blindly and you get a loop of infinite forwarding which in turn crashes the network. With STP however you can have loops in your network but STP will disable them **until** the tree is rebuilt due to a change in the topology. What this means is if you have a network running spanning tree, and a few links go down you have other links that will come up thus you have redundancy and your network won't crash.

TRILL is a new protocol that provides with without the need to shutdown links. Thus it provides the multi-path redundancy you are talking about.